# Mystery Internal CD Rom Interface

Tags: cd-drive

I found an old Internal CD Rom for an older Dell Laptop. Rather than just sell it, or trash it I was wondering if there was an interface that would let me use it as an external drive.
The drive is a 2001 UJDA330 CD-R/RW Drive DC5V Kyushu Matsushita. It has a 40 Pin male interface - See Picture. Evidently it transfers data and gets power through the 40 pin interface - Similar to the old Sun Computers design.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

.

[image]

Comment: Unscrew and Pull that adapter off of it to see the true interface, that is a dell proprietary adapter. There are several different ones (pcmcia/sata) over the years.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking of converting internal Optical drive(usually found in laptops) to an external one, then yes it can be done. There are a number of enclosures available for that.

Comment: I have been unable to find a 40 pin interface with power. What in the name of such an interface?

Comment: This should work, as an example:  https://www.amazon.com/1-8-inch-40pin-Enclosure-USB2-0-Cables/dp/B01H8HDMWK

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be the creature. Thank you.